# How to get the thumbnail of animated .gif files without losing animation if any one contains using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a animated .gif images. I want to resize the images to specific height/width without losing the aniamtion part and want an output as stream.

or
Getthumbnail for the same images without losing the animation.

I have gone through the solutions mention related the same but not being able to solve.

Would any one mind providing sample code for the same.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: How have you created the image? If you could share the code?

Comment: Thanks Rameez. I managed to do through some other way working quite ok.

Answer (score 0):

(disclaimer - I work for Atalasoft)

If you use the [Photo Free version of our toolkit](http://www.atalasoft.com/free-dotnet-image-sdk), you can do something this:

```
// read in all the frames
GifDecoder decoder = new GifDecoder();
ImageInfo info = decoder.GetImageInfo(mySourceStream);
GifFrameCollection collection = decoder.Frames;

foreach (GifFrameFrame frame in collection)
{
    // resize each frame
    AtalaImage image = frame.Image;
    AtalaImage resizedImage = new ReampleCommand(new Size(newWidth, newHeight)).Apply(image).Image;
    frame.Image = resizedImage;
}
// set the size in the collection
collection.Width = newWith;
collection.Height = newHeight;

// save out to a stream
GifEncoder encoder = new GifEncoder();
encoder.Save(outputStream, collection, null);
```

Comment: Thanks plinth but it is something to download upto 98mb then you can try. But I am able to do it by some other way.